# In case of failed PlaySound(), is it possible to retrieve last error status?

Tags: windows, winapi, winmm

I'm asking because universal `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_SUCCESS` even if preceding `PlaySound()` call returned `FALSE`. I'm aware what `winmm` have specific error functions for waveOut, mixer, etc, is there a function which reflects last `PlaySound()` status?

Comment: What do you want to do? Could you not maybe use an if statement? (i.e. if PlaySound() returns false, then print out a statement to the debugger?)

Answer (score 1):

No. [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743680%28VS.85%29.aspx) works or it doesn't, and it doesn't tell you why when it fails. But it's a pretty simple function; it it fails then it's almost always because the sound you told it to play isn't there.

Comment: I disagree about "primitive function", there at least 2 *distinct* error states currently supported (see SND_NODEFAULT and SND_NOSTOP flags).